# Can I update an external state inside a reducer hook?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a slider with a progress countdown bar, every 10s the slider show the next image..  basically, the problem is that I need to set the time 10s every time the dispatch fired off

at the moment is keeping the same seconds so if you wait 3 seconds 9,8,7 and you click next, it shows the next image but the time starts at 7, I need to set the time when the reduces is called

how can I call setCount when the reducer is called is my question?

```
const initialState = {scene: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case 'next':        
        //setCount()====> 'setCount' is not defined
        return {scene: state.scene + 1};
      case 'prev':
        return {scene: state.scene - 1};
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
}


function App() {
    const limitSlider = 17
    const initialCount = 10
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const [currentCount, setCount] = useState(initialCount);



    useEffect(
        () =>{
            const timer = () => setCount(currentCount - 1);

            if (currentCount <= 0) {

                //stop countdown 
                if ( state.scene === limitSlider) return

                //change to the next scene
                dispatch( {type: 'next'} )

                //set count
                setCount(10)
                return;
            }

            //reset interval
            const id = setInterval(timer, 1000);
            return () => clearInterval(id);
    },[currentCount, state.scene])


    return (
        <>



                scene: {state.scene} time: {currentCount}

                <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'prev' })} disabled={state.scene === 0}>-</button>
                <progress max="" value={`${currentCount}%`}> </progress> // progress is not working need to figure it out first the seconds
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'next'})} disabled={state.scene === limitSlider}>+</button>


        </>
  );
}
```

sorry I tried to compile it using the prebuilt snippet from stackoverflow,  but had some errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your state in a single reducer :

```
const initialState = {
  scene: 0,
  count: 10
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "next":
      return { scene: state.scene + 1, count: 10 };
    case "prev":
      return { scene: state.scene - 1, count: 10 };
    case "inc":
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };  
    case "dec":
      return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };           
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```

Complete code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-chatterjee-hwjm7

Comment: Awesome!!... didn't think of this, much better than my solution..thanks

Comment: do you know how can I stop rendering the app components after every second? - Thanks https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-keller-1i7un

Comment: Why ? if it does not render, then you can not update the timer

Comment: what I meant is to render the app just one time and not every sec... I have like 20  components inside app, each one with their own animations and audio...and rendering everything every seconds it's a bit messy... 

idealy I only need to listen to the scene variable... when it changes I changed the content,..  I used usecallback and memo but with not luck, I think because the time is in a reducer it's just rendering everything

Comment: I just created this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136011/how-to-stop-rendering-all-the-components-on-every-second-when-using-a-countdown

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved the problem just having the `setcount()`, inside the onclick, don't know if this is the way or if there is another way to call it after the reducer

```
<button onClick={() => {
                    setCount(initialCount);
                    dispatch({type: 'prev' })
                }} disabled={state.scene === 0}>-</button>

                <progress max="1%" value={`${currentCount}%`}> </progress>

                <button onClick={() => {
                    setCount(initialCount);
                    dispatch({type: 'next'})}} disabled={state.scene === lastScene}>+</button>
```